# knex.js Error message insert into postgreSQL

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, knex.js

Knex.js Error message when trying to insert into postgreSQL

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const knex = require("./db/db");

 //middlewares
 app.use(cors());
 app.use(express.json());
 //routes
 //creating a task

 app.post("/task", async (req, res) => {
 const { name } = req.body;
 const newtask = await knex
  .raw("insert into todo (name) values ($1)", [name])
  .then(() => {
   knex
    .select()
    .from("todo")
    .then(() => {
      res.send(newtask.row);
     });
   });
 });
```

throw new Error(`Expected ${expectedBindings} bindings, saw ${index}`);
^

Error: Expected 1 bindings, saw 0

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it right.
Replace your `$1` with just a question mark `(?)` and knex will allow it.

Also - the way you are combining await and .then doesnt make sense to me.
To clarify what I would do:

```
const newTask = await knex.raw(‘INSERT INTO todo (name) VALUES (?);’, [name]);
const allTasks = await knex.from(‘todo’).select();
res.send(allTasks);
```

Another simplified way to do this with nicer knex syntax:

```
const newTask = await knex(‘todo’).insert({ name });
const allTasks = await knex(‘todo’).select();
res.send(allTasks);
```

Note that the response object doesnt contain `rows` unless it is a raw query.
Lastly, maybe check that `name` actually exists after trying to destructure it - people will try sending the weirdest things online :)

Good luck!